# What happened to Brakiss?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I read *The New Rebellion* a *Star Wars* novel set 13 years after *Return of the Jedi*. Luke's big bad apprentice is chilling on a planet making droids. Does he ever do anything in future books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the events of *The New Rebellion*, Brakiss was forced to flee, ending up in the Deep Core working as a go-between for some Imperial Remnant warlords. He eventually established a training facility, the [Shadow Academy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shadow_Academy) to train Dark Jedi with the intent of assaulting Luke Skywalker's training facility on Yavin 4, as shown in the [Young Jedi Knights](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Young_Jedi_Knights) series of books. His forces were defeated and he died when an internal conflict within his forces resulted in the Shadow Academy's self-destruct mechanism being engaged.